# In Objective-C where is textfielddoneediting originally declared?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I've performed a pretty exhaustive search of the documentation namely: UIViewController, UITextField, and UITextFieldDelegate, but I can't figure out where the method "textFieldDoneEditing" is originally declared.

I know that I have to use it in my ViewController to get the keypad to disappear in this manner:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

But is method part of a protocol that is inherently implemented by UIViewController?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `textFieldDidEndEditing` ?

Comment: No, I did not, textFieldDidEndEditing is part of the <UITextFieldDelegate> prototype, and it returns void, whereas textfieldDoneEditing returns an IBAction

Comment: Did you create that yourself ? and are you linking that with the `First Responder` in you IB ? There is no method with that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the other code,  I suspect this was connected to the textfield via interface builder connecting to the Editing Did End event.  There is no textFieldDoneEditing method in any of UITextField parent classes.

Comment: That is correct, it was linked via IB to interpret the event "DidEndOnExit" -- Also, said I had said in my original post, all the examples I have read indicate that this method needs to be implemented, but again, where is it originally coming from.

Comment: when you connect the action from the event you can name the method anything you would like.  The event is part of the delegate (UITextFieldDelegate http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

Comment: Ahh...now I get it, makes sense. However, I don't believe that the event is part of the delegate, since the delegate does not to be implemented in order for this to work. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: textFieldDoneEditing is not part of the delegate protocol, and all of the methods in the delegate protocol are optional.  In this case, it appears that the method textFieldDoneEditing is linked to the protocol method textFieldDidEndEditing (or similiar) via interface builder. because it is linked in IB it is not 'defined' in the traditional sense.